# Jar files - exceptions

Tags: java, jar, exception

I have a jar file. It has 2 classes. I ran it in cmd and it gave a list of exceptions. When I ran it again it did run only giving me access to the first login class. I was wondering if there is a command for seeing those exceptions again? I would like to try and address them.

Comment: This is where "reproduction steps" are helpful. You can't magically jump to code where it will error, you need to take steps to get there ;)

Comment: We really require the contents of the executable jar file along with the source to the java (I assume) files.

Comment: Is there any exception information? Can you attach them in your question?

Comment: I think the OP is asking if there is a tool or command that is part of Java that records history of previous executions. I don't think there is... @Angela can you post more of your code or the exceptions you saw in order to help us understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you closed the cmd and cannot see those outputs anymore. There is no native way to see the logs of cmd. So, you need to reproduce the conditions that gave those errors and run again might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to see exactly what your code is doing is to use Test Driven Development (TDD). With TDD you can exercise every line of your code, including throwing exceptions at specific lines.

Here are a few exception examples using jUnit and Mockito:

```
public class MyClass{
   private List<String> field;
   public void doStuff(){
      System.out.println("Before calling s.size()");
      s.size();
   }

   public void setField(List<String> s){
      field = s;
   }
}

/*imports need to go here*/
public class MyTest {
MyObject obj; //the class under test
@Mock List mock;

@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void throw_null_pointer_exception_on_purpose(){
    obj = new MyObject();
   //obj.field == null
    obj.doStuff(); //throws NullPointerException when s.size() is called in doStuff() method
}

@Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
public void throw_runtime_exception_on_purpose(){
    obj = new MyObject();
    obj.setField(mock);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).size();
    obj.doStuff(); //throws RuntimeException when s.size() is called in the doStuff() method.
}
}
```

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development for more information.